# How to set cameras type to Orthographic with python scripting

Tags: python, scripting, camera

I'm trying to add some cameras to my scene that are orthographic. For this I am using:

```
add camera
bpy.ops.object.camera_add(view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(-12, 12, 12), rotation=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, ))

 make the camera of type orthographic
bpy.data.cameras["camera.001"].type('ORTHO')
```

I want all the cameras to be Orthographic, but i don't know how. I cant get this to work. I know that it is an ENUM, but i dont know what to do with it.

How can I set these to be orthographic?

Comment: Python doesn't have enums. It's just a string.

Comment: Enums were added in python 3.4 http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values to set for the types are: 
`'PANO'`, `'PERSP'` and `'ORTHO'` in your case, you would loop over all objects and check whether they are cameras and assign `'ORTHO'`

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.type == 'CAMERA':
        print(obj.data.type)
        obj.data.type = 'ORTHO'
```

Answer (score 5):

Orthographic can be set with:

```
bpy.data.cameras['Camera'].type = 'ORTHO'
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. It's a bit weird though that I have to set `ORTHO` with `cam = bpy.data.cameras['Camera']` after having set `location` with `cam = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]`. Am I doing things wrongly?

Comment: @SibbsGambling Sorry, I don't know what you mean. Feel free to ask a new question if you have an issue.

Comment: Oh just that `bpy.data.cameras['Camera']` doesn't have a `location` attribute. To set that attribute, I need to do `bpy.data.objects["Camera"]`. I said it's weird because essentially it's the same thing, but I need to retrieve it differently for setting different attributes.

Comment: You would see the same thing for curves or armatures. When you're accessing `bpy.data.cameras` you're not accessing the camera object you're accessing the camera *datablock* which is then attached to the camera *object*. Similar issue [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14889/how-to-get-an-armature-by-name-in-python-and-get-access-to-its-bones/14896#14896). If you need more information it's better to ask as a separate question as comments aren't for this kind of discussion.

Comment: This is so very helpful! Thanks for the explanation!