# How to get an armature by name in Python and get access to its bones?

Tags: python, scripting, armature

I want to retrieve an armature by name and access its bones. However, this doesn't work:

```
armature = bpy.data.objects["rig"]
bones = armature.bones
```

It gives the error

> 'Object' object has no attribute 'bones'`

The `"rig"` object is found, and the armature variable holds a `bpy_struct` after the first line executes.

So how do I access the bone data?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`"rig"` is an [Object](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.Object.html) datablock, bone data however is part of an [Armature](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.Armature.html) datablock.

What you are looking for is `bpy.data.objects["rig"].data`, which is the armature:

```
# Active object
ob = bpy.context.object

if ob.type == 'ARMATURE':
    armature = ob.data

    for bone in armature.bones:
        print(bone.name)
```

An armature has two bone collections:

- `.bones`
- `.edit_bones`

Note that `.edit_bones` are only accessible if the armature is in *Edit Mode*.
See [EditBones, PoseBones, Bone... Bones](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/info_gotcha.html#editbones-posebones-bone-bones)

There is a third kind of bone data structure for [pose bones](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.PoseBone.html#bpy.types.PoseBone), which is referenced by the object and not the armature:

```
bpy.data.objects["rig"].pose.bones
```